# ModalPopupExtender dosenot show up and display blank page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

> hi,
>   I had aproblem on model popup extender as I used it well , I did my code well .but when I was testing it it didnot show up only blank page appeared.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

.ModalPopupBG
        {
            background-color: #666699;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            opacity: 0.7;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
        }

```
    .btnadd
    {
        background-image: url('Content/Images/add.png');
        height: 27px;
        width: 78px;
        border: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .calhover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    .z
    {
        clear: both;
        height: 1px;
    }
    .tile
    {
        background-image: url('Content/Images/tile.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        width: 437px;
        background-position: right;
        color: White;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .activetab
    {
        background-color: Green;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .accordion
    {
        width: 770px;
    }

    .accordionHeader
    {
        border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2E4d7B;
        font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .accordionHeaderSelected
    {
        border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;
        color: white;
        background-color: #5078B3;
        font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .accordionContent
    {
        background-color: #D3DEEF;
        border: 1px dashed #2F4F4F;
        border-top: none;
        padding: 5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateCheckBox1(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>").checked == true) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateCheckBox2(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox2.ClientID %>").checked == true) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateCheckBox3(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox3.ClientID %>").checked == true) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="body_con ">
                        <div class="bf_body_d">
                            <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="body_content" valign="top">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="border: #3399FF">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="100%" class="style1" align="left">
                                                                <h3 style="color: Gray; font-size: large;">
                                                                    Questions</h3>
                                                                <h2>
                                                                    Please be aware that your answer on both questions might be used by HR to screen
                                                                    your application.</h2>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="style1" align="left">
                                                                <asp:DataList ID="Dl_Question" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Dl_Question_ItemDataBound"
                                                                    OnItemCommand="Dl_Question_ItemCommand">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_QID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label><br />
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                                                        <textarea id="Txt_Answer" cols="75" rows="3" runat="server"></textarea>
                                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator22" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_Answer"
                                                                            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="question">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:DataList>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="100%" class="style1" align="left" valign="top">
                                                                <h3 style="color: Gray; font-size: medium;">
                                                                    Upload Your CV
                                                                </h3>
                                                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FU_CV" runat="server" />
                                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FU_CV"
                                                                    ErrorMessage="File size should not be greater than 4 MB." OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator22" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FU_CV"
                                                                    ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="question">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                                                                        <h2 style="color: Blue; font-size: medium;">
                                                                            Please certify the information supplied before submitting your CV by checking the
                                                                            checkbox below .</h2>
                                                                        <h2 class="dark_gray">
                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                                                            <span>I certify that all answers given herein are true and complete.
                                                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                                                    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox1" ValidationGroup="question"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                            <br />
                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                                                                            <span>I authorize investigation of all statements contained in this application for
                                                                                employment as may be necessary in arriving at an employment decision.
                                                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                                                    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox2" ValidationGroup="question"></asp:CustomValidator></span>
                                                                            <br />
                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                                                                            <span>I hereby certify that all the above data is true and correct. If proven otherwise,
                                                                                I will be dismissed without any notice or commitment from the employer.
                                                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"
                                                                                    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox3" ValidationGroup="question"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </h2>
                                                                    </asp:Panel>
                                                                    <div align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="preup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/down.png" OnClick="preup_Click" />
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="BT_submit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/finish.png"
                                                                            OnClick="BT_submit_Click" ValidationGroup="question" /></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <!--  Kareem end here plz -->
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
</cc1:TabContainer>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalpopup" runat="server" OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="hfield"
    PopupControlID="display" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfield" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel ID="display" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img src="Content/Images/warning.png" />
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="OK" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

```
 protected void BT_submit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    string File = "~/CvFiles/" + FU_CV.FileName;
    if (FU_CV.FileBytes.Length > 4194304)
    {
        modalpopup.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem as I added `TargetControlID` to `hidden field's ID` but when I replaced it with the ID of submit button `"BT_submit"` it worked well.